# Link closest points accross altitudes in Matlab and form chains

Tags: matlab, 3d, delaunay, neighbours, closest-points

I have a 3d matrix with scattered points (Nx4 matrix, x-y-z-data). My aim is to link the closest points together and register each chain in an Kx4 array (x, y, z, data), K being the chain length. The total number of chains depends on the points...
A particularity is that these lines only go upwards (z+), I don't want to link points on same z, or go down.

I have been trying different strategies so far, one being with another array shape (Mx4xNz - basically meaning the values were stacked per z's instead of being all on a 2d matrix):
[edited after some progress, using delaunay/nearestneighbor]

1. pick a point at level Zn
2. go to level Zn+1, look for the closest point in a range of coordinates x,y using delaunayTriangulation and nearestNeighbor
3. register the point into a vector

(I suspect there are other possibilities using nearestNeighbor with the Nx4 matrix, but i can't think how to 'direct' the search upwards and chain the successive points... )

I find myself with the following problem :
The finding of nearest point upwards seems to work well but in 1 direction only!!

Linking doesn't work:

[image: Linking doesn't work]

Linking works:

[image: Linking works]

During the loop I have the warning :
Warning: Duplicate data points have been detected and removed.
 The Triangulation indices are defined with respect to the unique set of points in
 delaunayTriangulation property X.

Lign=zeros(max_iter,4,s);

for i = 1:s;

```
pp_id=i; 

for  n=1:max_iter-1; 

    Wn=W(:,:,n); % W is the data 3d-matrix Mx4xNz
    Wnn=W(:,:,n+1);

    Point_n = Wn(pp_id,:); 

    xn= Point_n(1);
    yn= Point_n(2);
    zn= Point_n(3);
    vn= Point_n(4);

    if xn==0|yn==0|zn==0|vn==0;
        break
    end

    % Look for nearest neighbour at next level
    DT=delaunayTriangulation(Wnn(:,[1:2]));
    [pp_id, d]=nearestNeighbor(DT,[Point_n(1),Point_n(2)]); 

    % limit range
    if d>10 
        break
    end

    % extraction of values at new pp_id 
    Point_n=Wnn(pp_id,:);

    % register point in line
    Lign(n,:,i)=Point_n;

end
```

end

Anyone has an idea as to why this is happens?

Comment: Have you tried doing any clustering techniques?  http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/cluster-analysis.html

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar with these. kmeans looks interesting but i'm not sure how to define the clustering rule (in my case, closest neighbour upwards, within a certain range)?

Comment: How many points are talking about here? Dozens, hundreds, thousands? If it's small enough, a simple distance matrix would do, no?